# Apache 2.4.7 install issue

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache-2.4

I've just compiled and installed Apache 2.4.7 => /usr/local/apache2/
The issue I'm having is that the default version is used

```
apachectl -v
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -v
Apache/2.4.7 (Unix)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: how was installed Apache/2.2.22 ?

Comment: From the installer wizard.

Comment: What's the output of `whereis apachectl`? Chances are it's still pointing at your default install...

Comment: Yes, it points to /usr/sbin/apachectl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently i think  there are two Apache instance, one installed with the package manager and one you just installed by compiling from the source.

You can confirm the same by running

> dpkg --get-selections | grep apache

If apache2 is listed there, then there is two apache instance. You can un install the default one safely if there is no virtualhosts configured. Otherwise copy the virtualhost file and transfer them to the new installation. And then remove the apache2 using the package manager